# Incrementing Rank Value in Column

Tags: sql, netezza

I have a table with Customers, Products, and Rank.  Each customer has up to 5 products:

```
Customer, Product, Rank
 Cust A, Product 3, 1
 Cust A, Product 7, 2
 Cust A, Product 6, 3
 Cust B, Product 4, 1
 Cust B, Product 6, 3
 Cust B, Product 3, 5
```

I removed some of the rows (like Cust B Rank 2 and 4).

How can I go through the table and wherever there is a break in the rank (like the missing 2 and 4) for each customer and re-rank them (so they are 1,2,3 instead of 1,3,5)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, you don't have to change the data in the table.  You could just use the `row_number()` function when you query:

```
select customer, product,
       row_number() over (partition by customer order by rank) as rank
from t;
```

If you use this approach, then you don't have to worry about future deletions.

Okay, if you really do want to change the data, one method is a correlated subquery:

```
update t
    set rank = (select count(*)
                from t t2
                where t2.customer = t.customer and t2.rank <= t.rank
               );
```